# OpenShift GoLang Template parsing error in oc.exe command prompt: Unexpected unclosed action in if

Tags: go, openshift, command-prompt, go-templates, openshift-3

Please find the below script which I have used to fetch the running pods from openshift container

```
oc get pods -o template --template {{range.items}}{{if eq .status.phase "Running"}}{{.metadata.name}}{{.status.phase}}{{end}}{{end}}
```

[image: Script ran and error shown in the below image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple issues with your command, one being that you need to put a space between `range .items` and the main issue being that you did not put your template in quotes. This results in the template being read as `{{range.items}}{{if`, which will lead to the error above.

To fix this, put your template in quotes, but take care to escape all other quotes in your command as well:

```
oc get pods -o template --template "{{range .items}} {{if eq .status.phase \"Running\"}} {{.metadata.name}} {{.status.phase}} {{\"\\n\"}} {{end}} {{end}}"
```

Comment: Is the above script is running in command prompt ?
I also tried using this format above. But it ends up with Unicode error.
I will try again and share a screenshot.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Simon The above code worked. In one case I have used single quote like --template '{{range.items}}.....  If I could have used the double quote !!!

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the uppercase later on go 
You could not access field in lower case..

```
    {{range .items}}
              {{if .Status.Phase "Running"}}
                   {{.Metadata.Name}}
                   {{.Status.Phase}}
               {{end}}

    {{end}}
```